# Difference between mssql_connect and sqlsrv_connect

Tags: php, sql-server

I have just changed the connection driver (extension) from `mssql_connect` to work with `sqlsrv_connect`. Unfortunately things do not seem to work as I wanted. I'd appreciate if someone can tell me what’s wrong and how can I fix it.

Code excerpt:

```
//a oracle DB moudle with a generic functions such as 
//db_connect() db_query()

/// turn on verbose error reporting (15) to see all warnings and errors 
error_reporting(15);
//generic DB operations

// Global record . for using in 
$curr_rec = NULL;

function dbok($res)
{
    if($res==false){
        echo "DB error: "."FIXME need error mesg"."\n";
        exit;
    }
    return $res;
}

function db_now_expr()
{
    return "getdate()";
}

function db_is_connected($dbh)
{
    return $dbh>0;
}

function ensure_connected($dbh)
{
    if(!db_is_connected($dbh)) die("DB is not connected, operation failed");
    //echo "DEBUG: hdb=$dbh"; 
}

//connect to given database 
//return handler to DB


function dbo_logon($dbserver,$dbname)
{

    $tsql = ??????? ====>>> what should i put here???? 

    $dbserver = "computername\SQLEXPRESS";
    $dbname = MY_Database_name;

    $connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"BULL");

    $dbh=dbok(sqlsrv_connect($dbserver, $connectionOptions));
    dbok(sqlsrv_query($dbname,$dbh)); 

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $connectionOptions, $tsql );

    return $dbh;

}

//close DB
function dbo_logoff($dbh)
{
    if(!db_is_connected($dbh)) echo("DB disconnect error");
    sqlsrv_close($dbh);
}
```

Here is the original code using `mssql_connect`:

```
//a oracle DB module with a generic function such as 
//db_connect() db_query()

/// turn on verbose error reporting (15) to see all warnings and errors 
error_reporting(15);
//generic DB operations

// Global record . for using in 
$curr_rec = NULL;

function dbok($res)
{
    if($res==false){
        echo "DB error: "."FIXME need error mesg"."\n";
        exit;
    }
    return $res;
}

function db_now_expr()
{
    return "getdate()";
}

function db_is_connected($dbh)
{
    return $dbh>0;
}

function ensure_connected($dbh)
{
    if(!db_is_connected($dbh)) die("DB is not connected, operation failed");
    //echo "DEBUG: hdb=$dbh"; 
}

//connect to given database 
//return handler to DB
function dbo_logon($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname)
{
    // $dbh=dbok(mssql_pconnect($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpass));
    $dbh=dbok(mssql_connect($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpass));
    //error_log("connect to [$dbname]".date("His")." \r\n",3,"/tmpbull.log"); //DBEUG DELME
    dbok(mssql_select_db($dbname,$dbh));
    //dbo_exec($dbh,"alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='dd-mm-yyyy //hh24:mi:ss'");
    return $dbh;

}

//close DB
function dbo_logoff($dbh)
{
    if(!db_is_connected($dbh)) echo("DB disconnect error");
    mssql_close($dbh);
}
```

Note that I had to change the authentication method from SQL authentication to Windows authentication because `sqlsrv_connect` uses Windows authentication instead of SQL authentication. Is that right?

Comment: Define "do not seem to work as I wanted".

Answer (score 2):

I think these two links will help to understand **Difference between mssql and sqlsrv**

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/08/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-what-s-the-difference-part-1.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/10/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-what-s-the-difference-part-2.aspx

Though in short, to quote one of the articles:

> The **sqlsrv** driver is built, maintained, and supported by Microsoft`

and

> The **mssql** driver is a community-built driver.
>
> I’m not sure how recently this driver was updated or maintained as an official PHP extension, but as of the release of PHP 5.3, it is no longer available with PECL. A quick internet search turns up a few places to download the mssql driver, but none of them that I’ve found indicate that the driver is being actively maintained.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/08/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-what-s-the-difference-part-1.aspx

As for your code sample, see below:

> ```
> $dbserver = "computername\SQLEXPRESS";
>
> $dbname = "BULL";   
> $connetion = dbo_logon($dbserver,$dbname);  
> function dbo_logon($dbserver,$dbname) {  
>     $connectionOptions = array("Database"=>$dbname);  
>     $dbh=sqlsrv_connect($dbserver, $connectionOptions);  
>     if(!$dbh){  
>          die("Error in Database connection");  
>          return false;   
>     }  
>  return $dbh;   
>  }
> ```

I think this will work for the connection.**please note the code is not tested.**

Answer (score 0):

"The sqlsrv driver is built, maintained, and supported by Microsoft`" well right now Sep 2014, there is no official release to support php 5.6 last official release is from april 2012. MS style...